# Confusing behavior of SimpleEvaluationContext.forReadOnlyDataBinding() in SpEL

Tags: spring-el

I am reading Spring 5.1.3 reference docs, and [SpEL Type Conversion](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.1.3.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/core.html#expressions-type-conversion) gets following sample code:

```
class Simple {
    public List<Boolean> booleanList = new ArrayList<Boolean>();
}

Simple simple = new Simple();
simple.booleanList.add(true);

EvaluationContext context = SimpleEvaluationContext.forReadOnlyDataBinding().build();

// false is passed in here as a string. SpEL and the conversion service
// correctly recognize that it needs to be a Boolean and convert it
parser.parseExpression("booleanList[0]").setValue(context, simple, "false");

// b is false
Boolean b = simple.booleanList.get(0);
```

It works as the documents mentioned, and changes the value of the property, but according to Javadocs `forReadOnlyDataBinding()`

> Create a {@code SimpleEvaluationContext} for read-only access to public properties via {@link DataBindingPropertyAccessor}.

Shouldn't the SpEL Expression be read-only, and does not change the property value?

Answer (score 1):

The field's contents are mutable but the field itself is immutable.

i.e. you are not allowed to replace `booleanList` with a new array but there is nothing to prevent the contents of the existing array from being mutated.